# Search and convert to lower case on vim

Tags: regex, linux, vim

I have a code with `object.attribute` where attribute can be an array 
example: `object.SIZE_OF_IMAGE[0]` or a simple string. I want to search all occurrences `"object.attribute"` and replace it with `self.lowercase(attribute)` I want a regular expression on vim to do that.

I can use that `:%s/object.*/self./gc` and replace it manually but it is very slow.

Here are some examples:

`object.SIZE` to `self.size`

`object.SIZE_OF_IMAGE[0]` to `self.size_of_image[0]`

Comment: Could you give us a realistic before/after example? As is, your question doesn't contain a single uppercase character in code samples so it's hard to see what you want to convert to lowercase, which makes it barely understandable.

Answer (score 9):

You basically just need two things:

- Capture groups [`:help /\(`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28) let you store what's matched in between `\(...\)` and then reference it (via `\1`, `\2`, etc.) in the replacement (or even afterwards in the pattern itself).
- The [`:help s/\L`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s%2F%5CL) special replacement action that makes everything following lowercase.

This gives you the following command:

```
:%substitute/\<object\.\(\w\+\)/self.\L\1/g
```

Notes:

- I've established a *keyword start assertion* (`\<`) at the beginning to avoid matching `schlobject` as well.
- `\w\+` matches letters, digits, and underscores (so it fulfills your example); various alternatives are possible here.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/object\.([^ \(]*)(.*)/self.lowercase(\1)\2/g' file_name.txt
```

above command considers that your attribute is followed by space or "("

you can tweek this command based on your need

Answer (score 0):

Based  on  your  comment   above  that  the  attribute  part
*"finishes by space or [ or ("* you could match it with:

```
/object\.[^ [(]*
```

So,  to replace  it  with `self.attribute`  use a  capturing
group and `\L` to make everything lowercase:

```
:%s/\vobject\.([^ [(]*)/self.\L\1/g
```

Answer (score -1):

In the command mode try this

```
:1,$ s/object.attribute/self.lowercase(attribute)/g
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to change `object.WHATEVER_THING` to `self.whatever_thing`

Comment: attribute can be any string

Comment: @ChristianGibbons exactly but WHATEVER_THIN that finishes by space or [ or (